# How to figure out which of three equations: $y=-2x+1, y=2x+1, y=x+1$ is linearly dependent on the others?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three equations:

$$y=-2x+1$$
$$y=2x+1$$
$$y=x+1$$

I am trying to see which of these is linearly dependent on the others. Normally I can just eyeball it, but here it is very hard to see. Does anyone know a general method to see which equation is causing the linear dependency? thanks!

Comment: The general method is called "row reducing" or [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: They are pairwise independent, this means that if you remove any equation, the other two will be linearly independent

Comment: Which one is dependent is the wrong question to ask.  A set of equations is either dependent or independent.  It can be that a subset is dependent, but unless one of them is $y=0x+k$ you won't have just one dependent equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In truth, a *set* of equations itself is linearly (in)dependent; not some equation is linearly dependent on another one, although this is a common linguistic abuse.

As others have said, any two equations from your set of three form a linearly independent (sub)set, but the three of them form a linearly dependent set. There's no particular one that depends on the others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the system of equations is inconsistent in this case. Solving the first two equations, we get y = 1, x = 0, but that is obviously not what the last equation wants.

There is no way you can construct the linear dependency in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Add $3/4$ times the second to $1/4$ times the first and you get the third. So in that sense, the third depends on the first two.

But add $-3$ times the second to $4$ times the third and you get the first. So in that sense, the first depends on the latter two.

Similarly, there is a way to express the middle one as "depending" on the first and last.

So it's not about "which one" depends on the other two. As a whole, the set is a "dependent" set.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering how you found that it was 3/4 times the second, etc. I row-reduced, but I just get a row of zero's, which just tells me that they are linearly dependent. How did you exactly find the right coefficients? thanks!